# Doubts about how to combine CDI beans: SessionScoped and RequestScoped

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

My goal is to present a jsf page that has Create, Retrieve and Update features.
I decided to create different CDI beans and different composite components for each of this operations and then put it all together in the page.

So far so good, but i just finished and i discovered a really confusing bug, and i don't know how to fix it:

The CDI bean tool that does the CREATE operation is a @RequestScoped bean, so the input fields clean them selves after the request.(See the image bellow)

[image]

I have no problem at all with it(Just that warning i cant get rid off), it works fine.

The next gadget i created is a data table that can also edit the data. To do it i needed to use a @SessionScopped CDI bean.(See image below)

[image]

Here comes the problem:
When the page is rendered the @SessionScoped bean caches the data in the session, but when new data is inserted, using the @RequestScoped bean,the data goes to the data base but the datatable does not display the new entered values, because are not in the session.

So what should i do?
Here i will show you the two beans:

**THE CREATE BEAN**

```
@Named("subjectControllerCreate")
@RequestScoped
public class SubjectControllerCreate implements Serializable {

    private Subject currentSubject;
    @EJB
    private SubjectFacade ejbFacade;

    //INITIALIZATION
    public SubjectControllerCreate() {
        currentSubject = new Subject();
    }


    //CREATE


       public String create() {
            try {         
                    currentSubject.setCreationDate(new Date());
                    getSubjectFacade().create(currentSubject);//Adds the current subject to the database!
                    JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("SubjectCreated"));
                    return "";//Can perform a redirect here if we want
                //}
                //return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**THE UPDATE BEAN**

```
@Named("subjectControllerUpdate")
@SessionScoped
public class SubjectControllerUpdate implements Serializable {

    //Using DataModel<Subject> instead of List<Subject> is necessary in order to be able to get the current row.
    private DataModel<Subject> subjects;    
    @EJB
    private SubjectFacade ejbFacade;

    //INITIALIZATION   
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       subjects = new ListDataModel<Subject>(getSubjectFacade().findAll());
    }

    //RETRIEVE
    public DataModel<Subject> retrieve() {
        return subjects;
    }

    //UPDATE
    public void update() {
        getSubjectFacade().edit(subjects.getRowData());
    }

    //HELP METHODS
    //RETURN THE FACADE FOR DATA MANIPULATION(Best practice)
    private SubjectFacade getSubjectFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public DataModel<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(DataModel<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }        
}
```

Is it maybe possible to make the data table send some ajax request when detects that the Create dialog closes, to get the rest of the newly entered data?
If yes how could i do it?

**This is the markup for my datatable:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="allSubjects" var="subject" value="#{subjectControllerUpdate.subjects}" paginator="true" rows="7" >
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{subjectControllerUpdate.update()}"/>
            <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{subject.name}" style="width:200px" >
                <p:cellEditor>  
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{subject.name}"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                        <p:inputText value="#{subject.name}" style="width:100%"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>  
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{subject.description}" headerText="Description">               
                <p:cellEditor>  
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{subject.description}"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                        <p:inputText value="#{subject.description}" style="width:100%"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>    
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{subject.credits}" headerText="Credits" style="width:50px">
                <p:cellEditor>  
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{subject.credits}"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                        <p:inputText value="#{subject.credits}" style="width:100%"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">                   
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>         
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>    

</html>
```

Ill appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just inject the `@SessionScoped` bean into the `@RequestScoped` bean and when create is clicked, call a method refresh in the `@SessionScoped` bean?

Comment: Yes that sounds like the easiest and best option. It works now, Thanks!